# Shannon Entropy Inequality

Tags: inequality, information-theory, entropy

Suppose I observe $n$ data points which generate the empirical distribution $P_n$ with associated point mass probabilities $p_1,\ldots,p_m$ with $m \le n$. Suppose I now observe a new data point which is different from the first $n$, yielding $P_{n+1}$. I feel reasonably confident that $H(P_n) < H(P_{n+1})$ always, but I can't prove it in complete generality nor can I find a counterexample. Any ideas? I can't find a property/theorem to leverage for this situation (1.8 from [here](http://www.mtm.ufsc.br/~taneja/book/node6.html) looked temporarily promising but doesn't do it).

The question about what happens if the point isn't unique is answered in generality [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3380167/entropy-of-disjoint-vs-overlapping-mixture/3380168#3380168)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be the new sample. By the definition of the empirical distribution,

$P_{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+1} P_n + \frac{1}{n+1} \delta_x,$ where $\delta_x$ is the unit mass at $x$.

Since $x \not\in \mathrm{support}(P_n), $ this is a disjoint mixture of two distributions. As an exercise show that if $P = \lambda Q + (1-\lambda) R$ for $\lambda \in [0,1]$ and distributions $Q,R$ with disjoint support, then $$ H(P) = h_2(\lambda) + \lambda H(Q) + (1-\lambda) H(R),$$ where $h_2$ is binary entropy.

(This is ex. 2.10 in the 2nd edition of Cover and Thomas)

Now, we have $$ H(P_{n+1}) = h_2\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right) + \frac{n}{n+1} H(P_n) + 0.$$

So the question becomes if it holds that $$\frac{H(P_n)}{n+1} \overset{?}< h_2\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$

To show this, note first that since the support of $P_n$ has at most $n$ symbols, $H(P_n) \le \log n$. But then $$h_2\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)  = \frac{\log (n+1)}{n+1} + \frac{n}{n+1}\log \frac{n+1}{n} \ge \frac{\log n+1}{n+1} > \frac{H(P_n)}{n+1}. $$

Comment: Hella smooth, thanks!

Comment: Ah, cheers mate. You're welcome.

Comment: edited question to link to related proof, which you might be interested in.