# Entropy of Disjoint vs. Overlapping Mixture

Tags: inequality, probability-distributions, entropy

This question extends [this Shannon Entropy Inequality question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3324786/shannon-entropy-inequality/3325740#3325740). Fix the shapes but not locations of the pmfs of discrete distributions $P$ and $Q$ and let $R = \lambda P + (1-\lambda) Q$. Will the entropy of $R$ be larger if $P$ and $Q$ overlap or if they have disjoint support, in general?

Answer (score 1):

We have, if $P$ and $Q$ overlap
\begin{alignat*}{3}
H(R) &= &&-[\sum_{k \in P \setminus Q} \lambda P(k) \log(\lambda P(k)) + \sum_{k \in Q \setminus P} (1-\lambda) Q(k) \log((1-\lambda) Q(k)) \\ &&&+ \sum_{k \in Q \cap P} [\lambda P(k) + (1-\lambda) Q(k)] \log(\lambda P(k) + (1-\lambda) Q(k))] \\
&= &&-[\sum_{k \in P \setminus Q} \lambda P(k) \log(\lambda P(k)) + \sum_{k \in Q \setminus P} (1-\lambda) Q(k) \log((1-\lambda) Q(k)) \\ &&&+ \sum_{k \in Q \cap P} \lambda P(k) \log(\lambda P(k) + (1-\lambda) Q(k)) \\ &&&+ \sum_{k \in Q \cap P} (1-\lambda) Q(k) \log(\lambda P(k) + (1-\lambda) Q(k))] \\
&< &&-[\sum_{k \in P \setminus Q} \lambda P(k) \log(\lambda P(k)) + \sum_{k \in Q \setminus P} (1-\lambda) Q(k) \log((1-\lambda) Q(k)) \\ &&&+ \sum_{k \in Q \cap P} \lambda P(k) \log(\lambda P(k)) + \sum_{k \in Q \cap P} (1-\lambda) Q(k) \log((1-\lambda) Q(k))] \\
&= &&-[\sum_{k \in P} \lambda P(k) \log(\lambda P(k)) + \sum_{k \in Q} (1-\lambda) Q(k) \log((1-\lambda) Q(k))].
\end{alignat*}
This last line is the entropy if $P$ and $Q$ do not overlap.

Comment: Looks good to me. There's also a more operational proof: suppose for every symbol $i$ in the supports, I instead introduce $(i,p)$ and $(i,q)$, and let $P'$ be $P$ but supported on the $(i,p)$s instead of on the $i$s, and similarly $Q'$. $P'$ and $Q'$ are trivially disjoint. Let the mixture of these be called $R'$. Given a sample from $R',$ I can deterministically generate a sample from $R$ - I just forget the second label (pushing $i$ for $(i,p)$ or $(i,q)$). But then by the DPI, $H(R') \ge H(R),$ with strict inequality if the intersection of supports is non-zero.